# Scroll to EditText in NestedScrollView is not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-nestedscrollview

I have long scroll form, and I need to scroll to its position on form is not valid input (for example, scroll to email edit text when it's not valid email or empty field)

I am facing 2 issues with scroll to EditText inside NestedScrollView

1. When one edit text is focused, all times scroll to take me directly to the focused scroll view, not to provided view coordinate
2. When there is no focused item, it's scrolling in a bad way, the wanted Edittext showing trimmed from the button

**Note**: I am using NestedScrollView with CoordinateLayout
Below is the layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/full_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f5f6f5">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="@string/personal_details"
                android:textColor="#a1143c"
                android:textSize="14sp" />


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/step1.rel.full_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/step.1.title.full_name"
                    style="@style/business_form_header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/firstName" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/step.1.feild.full_name"
                    style="@style/business_form_field"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/step.1.title.full_name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/step1.rel.last_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/step.1.title.last_name"
                    style="@style/business_form_header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/last_name" />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/step.1.feild.last_name"
                    style="@style/business_form_field"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/step.1.title.last_name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <!--Rest Of Views-->

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

here is the style

```
<style name="business_form_field">
                <item name="android:background">@drawable/roundedallsideswhite</item>
                <item name="android:layout_marginStart">9dp</item>
                <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">9dp</item>
                <item name="android:textColor">#383838</item>
                <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
                <item name="android:gravity">start|center_vertical</item>
                <item name="android:imeOptions">actionNext</item>
                <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
                <item name="android:inputType">textAutoComplete</item>
                <item name="android:paddingStart">15dp</item>
                <item name="android:paddingEnd">15dp</item>
                <item name="android:lines">1</item>
                <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
                <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
            </style>
```

Comment: What EditText? What NestedScrollView? Post the layout xml file..

Comment: @SamuelRobert added